# Find pairs of elements for duplicated values in a vector - R

Tags: r

I have a vector with some of the elements repeated. I want to list all the pairs of indices with equal values.

i.e. given input

```
x <- c(1,2,3,2,4,3,2)
```

I want to generate the list

```
duplicate_x <- [[2,4,7],[3,6]]
```

How to solve this in R

Comment: What does `[[2,4,7],[3,6]]` represent?

Comment: indexes of the duplicated elements, 2,4,7 are the indexes that has value 2 etc.

Comment: `[[2,4,7],[3,6]]` is for python notation, in R you should use `list(c(2,4,7), c(3,6))` correspondingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dups = duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = T)

split(which(dups), x[dups])
#$`2`
#[1] 2 4 7
#
#$`3`
#[1] 3 6
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do:

```
dupEle <- unique(x[duplicated(x)])
lapply(dupEle, function(ele) which(x == ele))
[[1]]
[1] 2 4 7

[[2]]
[1] 3 6
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a speed test of the two solutions suggested.

```
find_dups = function(x) {
  dups = duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = T)

  split(which(dups), x[dups])
}
find_dups2 = function(x) {
  dupEle <- unique(x[duplicated(x)])
  lapply(dupEle, function(ele) which(x == ele))
}

dups_small = c(1,2,3,2,4,3,2)
set.seed(1)
dups_large = sample(0:9, size = 50, replace = T)
```

Results:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(find_dups(dups_small),
+                                find_dups2(dups_small))
Unit: microseconds
                   expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval cld
  find_dups(dups_small) 53.833 55.589 69.43074 57.491 66.4140 288.183   100   b
 find_dups2(dups_small) 13.166 15.215 28.82765 16.677 20.0415 523.119   100  a 

> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(find_dups(dups_large),
+                                find_dups2(dups_large))
Unit: microseconds
                   expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval cld
  find_dups(dups_large) 50.615 52.079 59.88706 53.834 64.9515 149.212   100   b
 find_dups2(dups_large) 25.747 28.965 37.14842 31.014 34.3780 289.354   100  a
```

So the duplicated-lapply solution is actually a much faster, somewhere between roughly 2 and and 3.5 times.